# JasperReporst 3.0.1 TableView available?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have some question to JasperReports Version 3.0.1.

I need to generate a table view with a list of objects I'll pass direct from my controller. Is there any tag or something? I downloaded the ireport 3.0.0 but I cannot find anything that sounds like a tableview... Can you post an example or a link to a manual?

Secend query is how can I expand the report so it will take 2 or more sites? My "detail" section is quite big and I got a message tak the elements "do not fit the page height".

Can I add another "detail" section so that the code is cleaner?

It is not possbile for my to update the jasper to the newest version - I have to work on 3.0.1....

Comment: There are a lot of questions in your post. `Can I add another "detail" section so that the code is cleaner?` - Yes, you can use several Detail bands

Comment: A lot? There are only 3 ;)